# Retrieve Luence Index using Solrj

Tags: java, solr, solrj, lucene

In my application, I need to find out which term occurred in which documents. This is fine if we have to find out for only one term, but I have to find out this "map" for all terms. An example below clarifies what exactly I am looking for :

I want to find out something like this (please consider we have a field "article_text" with text type general ) : So the index is going to be like this (as per my understandings) :

Term   : Doc Ids in which this term is found 
Akshay : 1, 2, 3
Russia : 4, 5,6
Japan  : 23,54,21
.
. and so on. I am trying to retrieve this kind of map for my application. The field "article_text" is multivalued. I want to retrieve this kind of map for all terms in one query.

In slightly related note, it would be great to know if we can get such index of tf.idf too using solrj.

Comment: If you want to find all documents that a term occurs in, why not just query for it?  Such as, `article_text:akshay`

Comment: I don't have have predefined search queries and I am about to perform an NLP operation on the doc ids return. Will perform it on all the terms in the index not on a single term.

Comment: A bit confused then, here:  "I want to retrieve this kind of map for all terms in one query."  What query?  Do you want to enumerate terms for a query, or do you want to enumerate all terms across the entire index?

Comment: all terms across the entire index. Not a specific term. Its kind of simple loop that I can imagine : go to first term, find docs in which it occurs, then go to second term and so on.

Comment: You could generate a map like that iterating TermVectors I suppose (see [IndexReader.getTermVector](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#getTermVectors(int))).  I find myself wondering why you want to, though?  This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: thanks. I checked its not XY problem. I have written an algorithm for document comparison. For that purpose I need such docIds.

Comment: can you please explain a bit about getTermVector. I am trying something like this in Solr (using solrj )for long but no result.

Comment: You've written an algorithm for document comparison, and so you need a complicated new method to recreate an existing lucene index in a feature-light, inefficient form?  Okay, but hopefully you see why I find this a little bit odd.  As far as using the call, you get the Terms instance, use it to get a TermsEnum, iterate through, collecting results, then go on to the next doc id.  You can get the termfreq and docfreq from the TermsEnum as you iterate through it, which should satisfy the last line of your question as well.